# Can anyone suggest time complexity of the following code

Tags: c++, time-complexity

According to me the time complexity should be O(nlogn) as the outer loop works until n/2^k =1 and inner loop works for n times. Can anyone tell if i'm correct or not.

```
 while(n){ 
  j=n; 
  while(j>1){ 
    j-=1; 
  } 
  n/=2; 
}
```

Comment: To get an intuition for such a problem you could literally count the number of inner iterations for the first 10 or 100 values for `n`. That will give you a hint as to what the analytical complexity might be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inner cycle does `n` iterations, outer each iteration divides `n` by 2, so there are `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2n` total iterations of the inner cycle and time complexity is `O(n)`, not `O(n log n)`.

Comment: In case the jump from `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` to `2n` is not clear to anyone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula